# Titanium dynamic height for TableViewRows

Tags: android, height, titanium

Titanium 3.3.0

Hi there. I have many problems trying to make my app dynamic height for the TableViewRows, I want to give them like a 15% of the device height, when I use the "height: 15%" property the row simply does not appear. And I'm using like "height: 150px" and the problems comes when I install the app in a 320x240 phone looks huge and in a 1920x1080 looks tiny obviusly.

How can I make the tableViewRow height dynamic based in the screen dimentions?

PS: Sorry about my english and thank yo so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To support same UI across different density devices i suggest to use dp as the unit of measure. Checkout [This link](https://developer.appcelerator.com/question/148337/how-to-achieve-same-layout-for-android-and-iphone-using-titanium) it is what you require.

For a detail study you can also refer the [Docs](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/guide/Layouts,_Positioning,_and_the_View_Hierarchy).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you my friend, I used the suffixed strings like "20dp" insteed of "20px" and it works perfectly.